# Can't seem to join two tables properly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

**Flightnumbers**

| flightnumber | departure_iata | arrival_iata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MF9370 | JFK | LAX |
| TK8201 | JFK | ORD |
| 9C8824. | JFK | ATL |

**Airports**

| code | airport_name | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JFK | John F Kennedy | New York |
| ATL. | Atlanta Int | Atlanta |
| LAX. | Los Angeles In | Los Angeles |

I would like to create is a list of all flights from John F Kennedy Airport including the arriving city and airport names. Something like:

| flightnumber | airport name | city name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MF9370 | Los Angeles In | Los Angeles |
| TK8201 | O'Hare Airport | Chicago |
| 9C8824. | Atlanta Int | Atlanta |

I created the following query

```
SELECT flightnumbers.flightnumber, flightnumbers.arrival_iata, flightnumbers.departure_iata, 
airports.code, airports.airport_name, airports.city_name
FROM flightnumbers
JOIN airports ON flightnumbers.arrival_iata = airports.code
WHERE flightnumbers.departure_iata = JFK
```

But there is no output.

When I change the JOIN statement in `JOIN airports ON flightnumbers.departure_iata = airports.code` it shows a list, but in that case the airport_name and airport_city are from the departing airport. John F Kennedy in this case.

How can I fix this? Messing around with this for more then a day and can't find out what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: some of your airports codes and other fields have trailing `.` is that expected?

Comment: No, but that is something stackoverflow does when creating the tables. Removed them.

Comment: = JFK JFK should be quoted

Comment: Your query does throw an error - which you should heed and post in the question.ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'JFK' in 'where clause'

Comment: You are right, sorry. The error is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: Please share more details - for example, how is this related to PHP?

Comment: Have you checked mysql is up and running?

Comment: Yes it is. When I change the JOIN statement as mentioned in my post it shows data.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to put quote on `JFK`
Try this :

```
SELECT f.flightnumber, a.airport_name, a.city_name
FROM flightnumbers f
JOIN airports a ON a.code = f.arrival_iata 
WHERE f.departure_iata = 'JFK';
```

Comment: It shows an "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 503 (Service Unavailable). I try to fetch the code in datatables and there it shows https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Comment: What is "this"? Please explain what you've changed, and why, such that others can learn from it

Comment: @stevv i think if the question is from the MySQL side, this will answer your question, otherwise, if still failed, maybe it has not come from mysql

Answer (score 1):

You should get result if you add quotes on your `'JFK'`?

```
SELECT fn.flightnumber,ap.airport_name, ap.city_name
FROM flightnumbers fn
JOIN airports ap ON fn.arrival_iata = ap.code
WHERE fn.departure_iata = 'JFK'  <<<<-------------<<<------------
```

Comment: I did quote it in my PHP, sorry

Comment: What the query returns?

Comment: @stevv test the query separately in Workbench or phpMyAdmin, so it doesn't get mixed up with other problems in your PHP, and you'll get better error messages. If there's actually a problem in your PHP, we'd need to see that code

Comment: @ADyson great advice. When I use the query in phpMyAdmin it shows the loading spinner for a few minutes before showing the results.  There is a notification that the current selection doesn't contain a unique column.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny in phpMyAdmin the query returns the expected results only after a few minutes. PMA also shows a notification that there isn't a unique column available.

Comment: @stevv if it takes a few minutes, the 503 is probably the result of PHP or mysql timing out before it could complete the request. Maybe your database needs optimising, or your query, or you need to consider whether you need to return so much data at once. Either that or your server is just hopeless.